# titlesec package: how do I get the title on the right and the number on the left?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, titlesec

I am using `titlesec` to give a nicer look to my thesis. This is the setting at the moment:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\Huge\bfseries\color{black}\flushright}
{\thechapter}
{9em}
{}[\titlerule]
```

What happens is that:

- if the title is too short, the chapter number will be closer to the middle of the line.
  [image]
- if the title is too big, the text goes in new lines.
  [image]

Is there any way I can fix the number on the left, no matter what, and the text on the right with the same package? Is there any other package which would allow me to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [block]{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{\rlap{\thechapter}}{0em}
    {\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\filleft}[\titlerule\end{minipage}]

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{A very long chapter title to show that it will wrap correctly}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]